# How to do multiple file uploads from different input types in sharepoint list using csom/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am referring to the following url to implement upload functionality to sharepoint list(stored as attachments):[Uploading Attachment To The New Item On List Using “REST API” jQuery](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51320.uploading-attachment-to-the-new-item-on-list-using-rest-api-jquery.aspx)

In the above mentioned url there is just one input type used which is of file type.I have 6 input types having file type.
I can successfully upload from one input type
How do I achieve uploads for multiple inputs.

Adding attachments to the same array is not serving the purpose.I tried doing like this:

```
            $("#attachFilesHolder input:file").each(function () {
                if ($(this)[0].files[0]) {
                    fileArray.push({"Attachment": $(this)[0].files[0] });
                }
            });

            $("#attachFilesHolderUD input:file").each(function () {
                if ($(this)[0].files[0]) {
                    fileArray.push({"Attachment": $(this)[0].files[0] });
                }
            }); 

 arraycount += fileArray.length;
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
    <div class="form-group files" id="attachFilesHolder">
    <label for="form_middle">Supporting Document Upload </label>
   <input id="SupportingDocumentUpload" type="file" name="middlename" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event);" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group files" id="attachFilesHolderUD">
    <label for="form_middle">Supporting Document Upload </label>
    <input id="UndertakingDocumentUpload" type="file" name="middlename" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event);" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

Any solution anybody?

Comment: How are you declaring those other `<input type="file">`s? Can you show the HTML?

Comment: @acdcjunior-I have added html now

Comment: After that code runs `fileArray` should have two elements. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes it has two elements.The console output is as follows:File size:63

uploaded successfully
 Reload List Item- Success
File size:4

Comment: It goes till the File size of the second attachment.But after that it does not move ahead

Comment: But where else should it go to? You have two inputs. What did you actually want?

Comment: Both the attachments should go to the list.only one is getting attached to the 'Attachments' column of the list.